# bpcs steganography -mat2cell function

Tags: matlab, embedding, steganography

```
% lena -grayscale 512*512 size

a=imread('lena.png')
[c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8]=bitplane(a);
% taking lsb bitplane only
C{1} = c1;
curr_plane = C{1};
row = size(cover, 1)/8;
col = size(cover, 2)/8;

% divid it into 8*8 blocks
blocks = mat2cell(curr_plane, ones(1, row)*8, ones(1, col)*8);

for bi = 1,size(blocks,1)
for bj = 1,size(blocks,2)
    % for each block in curr_plane image , now identify the complex block
    % and replace it with secret blocks first and  then followed by conjugate
    % blocks until all information finally embedded
    my_8x8_block = blocks{bi,bj};
    figure,imshow(my_8x8_block)


end

end
```

I an doing bpcs steganography.......

In the following code only 8 blocks are displaying in figure even though size(blocks,1) is 64 . i need to access all individual blocks in bitplane image and proceed with complexity calculation and embedding.. please help me ?

Comment: You store the loaded image in `a`, but split the bitplanes for `cover`. If `size(blocks,1)` is truly 64, I can't see any reason why the loop would terminate sooner.

Comment: actually bitplane slicing is done over same lena image ,thats a mistake while posting. my question is why this loop terminate sooner??

Answer (score 0):

Your loop has incorrect syntax for its intended purpose. You want to use a colon separating the min and max values and not a comma.

```
for bi = 1:size(blocks,1)
    % do stuff
end do
```

I suggest you don't use `imshow` inside the loops, because it will spam you with figures. If you want to ensure that the code works correctly, just print the values of `bi` and `bj`.